# Logarithmic Properties for Equation

Tags: logarithms

What are the steps/logarithmic properties used to solve the equation 2^n=n^8? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the natural log of both sides, $$\ln 2^n=\ln n^8 \\ n\ln 2=8\ln n \\ \frac{n}{\ln n}=\frac{8}{\ln 2} $$ This is a transcendental equation, meaning it cannot be solved exactly. There are two solutions, approximately equal to $1.1$ and $43.56$ according to [Wolfram Alpha.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x/ln%28x%29=8/ln%282%29) You may also be interested in learning about the [Lambert W function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: It would be better to plot $\dfrac{\ln n}n$ , since it has a maximum in $n=e$, and the solutions become intuitively clear.

Answer (score 0):

NotNotLogical gave you the way to approach the problem which leads to a transcendental equation in $n$. The two roots are given by  $$x_1=-\frac{8 W\left(-\frac{\log (2)}{8}\right)}{\log (2)}$$ $$x_2=-\frac{8 W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\log (2)}{8}\right)}{\log (2)}$$

I a more general manner, equations such that $$a^n=n^b$$ have solutions given by $$x=-\frac{b W\left(-\frac{\log (a)}{b}\right)}{\log (a)}$$ which can potentially correspond to the two branches of Lambert function.

As Lucian nicely suggested, a look at function $\dfrac{\ln n}n$ is very useful since you should notice that there is no real solution if $\frac{\log (a)}{b} \gt e$ (this was established by Euler).